# What are the issues of using the "db-f1-micro" instance type for Cloud SQL in a production environment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

[Docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings) says

> Note: The db-f1-micro and db-g1-small machine types aren't included in the Cloud SQL SLA. These machine types are configured to use a shared-core CPU, and are designed to provide low-cost test and development instances only. Don't use them for production instances.

But, what specific problems can occur besides not being included in SLA and low Performance ?